# Force wrap between specific words

Tags: html, css

I'm building a site on which I have a title that consists of a long first word and two shorter words.

```
<h1>Looooooong short short.</h1>
```

I want this title to fit on one line if the screen is widde enough, and if the screen or container becomes too narrow for all three words, to break between the first and second, not the second and third words.

i.e. I want this:

```
Looooooong
short short
```

rather than this

```
Looooooong short
short
```

How can I do this in HTML/CSS?

[Also on JSBin if you prefer: jsbin.com/puzemex](http://jsbin.com/puzemex)

Comment: Looked into media queries?

Comment: Ideally I'd like it to happen automatically. As I understand it, a media query could fail if I decide, for example, that I want to change font size. Or am I understanding that wrong?

Comment: have you considered wrapping the looooooong word in an element? then you could use media queries to change it from block to inline (so ideally an inline element au natural) depending on viewport size?

Comment: non breakable space ? (short&nbsp;short)

Comment: @tibo:*facepalm* Can't believe I missed that. That's exactly what I want, Thanks! I'll accept that if you submit it as an answer.

Comment: ;) no worries. I have written it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use a non breakable space:

```
short&nbsp;short
```

For longer text here is a nice article:

http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/01/30/balancing-text-for-better-readability/